# How I make Android App name two lines?

Tags: android

I googled for that. 
When I made the app name multiple lines on the previous version, \n was used.

However, the above can not be applied to Nougat version of Android using google pixel.

How can I make Android app name two lines?

Answer (score 2):

Add \n in the string.xml file.

```
<string name="app_name">Hello\nWorld</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Use \n for a newline character.